# AsyncTask is not running, logcat showing as Suspending all threads took: time in ms

Tags: java, android, multithreading, performance, android-asynctask

I am trying to run an asynctask which can get all contacts info, but it is not running and showing as "Suspending all threads took: time in ms" in logcat

```
SyncContacts obSync = new SyncContacts(this);
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, HashMap<String,String>>() {
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
            }

            @Override
            protected HashMap<String,String> doInBackground(Void... params) {
                HashMap<String,String> pairs = new HashMap<String, String>();
                try {
                    System.out.println("succcccccccccccccccccces");
                    pairs = obSync.getContacts();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    System.out.println("Errrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return pairs;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(HashMap<String,String> result) {

            }
        }.execute();
```

This is the method in SyncContacts class

```
public HashMap<String,String> getContacts()  {
    HashMap<String,String> num_name_pairs = new HashMap<>();
    ArrayList<String> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
    ContentResolver cr = c.getContentResolver();
    Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

            if (Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[]{id}, null);
                while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                    String contactNumber = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)).trim().replace(" ","");
                    String name = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    if (!numbers.contains(contactNumber)) {
                        numbers.add(contactNumber);
                        num_name_pairs.put(contactNumber,name);
                    }
                    System.out.print("++++" + contactNumber + "->" + name + "...Success");
                }
                pCur.close();
            }

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        cursor.close();
    }
    return num_name_pairs;
}
```

the log cat is showing as

```
06-08 11:09:57.996 21330-21345/com.example.venky.snapbin W/art: Suspending    all threads took: 11.281ms
06-08 11:09:58.015 21330-23820/com.example.venky.snapbin I/art: Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 22422(882KB) AllocSpace objects, 2(38MB) LOS objects, 6% free, 54MB/58MB, paused 1.882ms total 49.168ms
```

Comment: AsycTask is used do to small work in background. And your logcat is showing that it is taking more than 10s, thus it is getting suspended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line 
suspending all thread took: some time

is normal as it show that GC feels to clean some memory to allocate it some where else, it simply means that either it has done its work or nothing to do here, you can check with using debug if your method is called either or not, GC remove thread of async as it feel to free memory that is not in use.

second line means it freed some amount of memory as result of GC on collection.

You should check first your method then is cursor is returning some value or there is case with you cursor.

Hope this will solve your problem.